# Checking the size of a json file

Tags: php

I have google a few examples but none seem to be working, what i'm trying to do:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    // json parse   
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    // save the json files for later
    // make sure they contain data
    if(filesize($json) < 16 && empty(trim(file_get_contents($json))) )
    {
        $file = 'links-'.rand(10000000,99999999).".txt";
        file_put_contents('Links/' . trim($file), $json);       
    }
}
?>
```

If the file size is empty, don't create the file, but the above code still does (that is the latest code i have tried), am i missing something obvious here?

Comment: `file_get_contents('php://input')` is not a file, it's the body of post (the json itself in your case)

Comment: As @chumkiu mentioned, $file is the string variable which stores the actual json. So, you can use Object.keys($json).length to find if the json is empty or have contents in it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file_get_contents() function reads the content into a string. Once it's in memory you don't need to try and read it again.

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    // populate the json variable   
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    // if the variable is not empty
    // save the content for later
    if (!empty($json))
    {
        $file = 'links-'.rand(10000000,99999999).".txt";
        file_put_contents('Links/' . trim($file), $json);       
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the very simple solution is decode the json and you can now check if the decoded json is an empty array.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($json);// decode json`
if (empty($json)) {
   // json is empty
}
```